# Missing terminal

Tags: 14.04

New to Ubuntu but highly interested, I have a problem with 14.04 in locating the terminal for command lines? As an alternative to GNOME Terminal, which I assumed would have been installed, I have tried to download GUAKE Terminal but am prevented by a repetitive error message indicating that the download 'requires the installation of untrusted packages' for which I have the options of ('OK' or 'Repair'). Activation of either has no effect on subsequent repeats, always linked to my hitting the installation button.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal for the GNOME environment can be opened one of two ways:

1. Applications menu -> Accessories -> Terminal.
2. Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Do either of those get you to a terminal environment?

Answer (score 0):

[Guake](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guake/) is in the repository.  You can install applications from the repository by using apt-get.

Type this at the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-get
```

If you get an error during the install, please post the exact error.

Most errors associated with installing applications from the repository can be resolved with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

By the way you can get to the default terminal (`gnome-terminal`) by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Of course you can also get to the default terminal by typing `terminal` in the search field of Ubuntu Launch button.  `xterm` is also a terminal that you can use for running commandlines.

Comment: Maybe you should mention `xterm` at the top of the question . . .I was just about to downvote your answer for saying "use this command" while OP cannot find terminal in the first place , hehe

Comment: It appeared theOP had already used the terminal cli to install Guake and was having problems with his cli attempt to install it.  I thought about telling him to go directly to the Software center or Synaptic to perform the install, but it might not be easy to see the exact errors he was getting.  So I suggested that he use the cli `apt-get` to perform the install.  He has a similar question from yesterday which gave many variations including pictures of how to get to the terminal.  Glad you read my full scope before marking as `not useful`.

Comment: @Serg I was trying to fix the OP's effort to resolve his install attempt which appeared to be a significant part of his new question.

Comment: My guess is that OP went to software center upon not finding terminal. Errors do show up there as well though.

Comment: Ok, keep doing the good job